# JavaScript – Modularize for-loop of a method

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

```
I have a function like this:

function makeSummary(people){
    const myList = []
    for (int i = 0; i < people.length; i++){
          myList.push({
            fullName: person.firstName + " " + person.lastName,
            title: person.title,
          })
    }
    return myList
}
```

which, given a list of people, constructs a slightly modified version of the list.

Is there any way I can pass the object that's constructed on any step of the for loop as a parameter?

I'd like to modularize this function for further reuse (this is just an example, my real code is a lot bigger, so it makes much more sense there, but the scenario is the same).

So, I'd like there to be an argument where I pass something like:

```
{
     fullName: person.firstName + " " + person.lastName,
     title: person.title,
}
```

and for the next function call, I could pass:

```
{
     fullName: person.firstName + " " + person.lastName,
     description: person.description,
}
```

and the method should know that that's the object that should be added at every step in the for-loop.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by modularize further? To do what exactly?

Comment: @charlietfl to modify the function in such a way that I can pass something like the objects I presented as an argument, so the function would work with that instead of having to hardcode the construction of the objects when pushing them to the list. Does that make more sense?

Comment: You can simply move your object building code to a helper function and pass it as a parameter in `makeSummary(people, helper)`, now you can pass helper function as per your need

Comment: Not really. what is the higher level problem you are trying to solve? What you are probably looking for is a class that you can pass a people object into and return a new instance That class would have a getter or)setter) for the fullname and any other methods you might need

Comment: @charlietfl the makeSummary method in my real code is a lot bigger, but it always works the same way except for the object that is being returned, so the keys and values vary. So to counteract that, I copy-pasted the makeSummary method all over the code and changed the object, but now I'd like to find a more modular approach without so much duplication.

Comment: That's where using a class would help. The makeSummary method would be a part of the prototype  for that class

Comment: @charlietfl thanks, got if figured out. It's been a long day... :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply move your hard coding of the object from makeSummary function, instead pass it as parameter. which will give you flexibility of defining helper function as per your need.

```
function makeSummary(people, helper){
    const myList = []
    for (int i = 0; i < people.length; i++){
          myList.push(helper(people[i])
    }
    return myList
}


function helper1(person){
  return {
      fullName: person.firstName + " " + person.lastName,
      title: person.title,
  }
}

function helper2(person){
  return {
      fullName: person.firstName + " " + person.lastName,
      description: person.description,
  }
}

//call it like this
makeSummary(people, helper1)
makeSummary(people, helper2)
```